# How do I launch my Rails server in debug mode in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: debugging, ruby-on-rails-5, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 on Mac High Sierra.  I have imported a Rails 5 project set up as an API only project.  How do I launch my Rails server in debug mode from Aptana?  I would like to do some debugging, but I can't figure out how to launch the server.  I have created my debugging configuration like so

[image]

but when I run my debugger it obviously doesn't connect to the server because the server isn't started ...

[image]

How do I launch my server in debug mode from Aptana (Note it is not an option to use a different IDE at this time)?